# php mail works but I'm unable to send mail to company webmail

Tags: php, apache, email, joomla

I'm trying to set up a contact form module in joomla website. the contact module works great for every of my personal email addresses such as xxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com or xxxxxxxxxxxx@libero.it, ect. But when I test it with my client's company mail recipient the mail function fails do to its work.

In order to get some more informations about the failure i set mailsender property to my personal mail address as follows:

```
$mailSender->setSender('xxxxxxx@libero.it');
$mailSender->addReplyTo('xxxxxxx@libero.it');
```

and this is what i got:

The original message was received at Sun, 21 Oct 2012 15:05:00 +0200
from apache@localhost

----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----

```
info@xxxxxx.it
(reason: 553 5.3.0 <info@xxxxxx.it>... No such user here)
(expanded from: info@xxxxxx.it)
```

----- Transcript of session follows -----

```
... while talking to [127.0.0.1]:
>>> DATA
<<< 553 5.3.0 <info@xxxxxx.it>... No such user here
550 5.1.1 info@xxxxxx.it... User unknown
<<< 503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
```

and in the attached file this:

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; xxxxxx.yyyyyyy.com
Arrival-Date: Sun, 21 Oct 2012 15:05:00 +0200

Final-Recipient: RFC822; info@xxxxxx.it
Action: failed
Status: 5.3.0
Remote-MTA: DNS; [127.0.0.1]
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 553 5.3.0 <info@xxxxxx.it>... No such user here
Last-Attempt-Date: Sun, 21 Oct 2012 15:05:01 +0200
```

It seems the company webmail doesn't accept mails from its own server.
Im not a email expert nor a expert php programmer.
any ideas?

Follows the part of my joomla module in which the mail function is instatiated and launched:

```
 $mailSender = &JFactory::getMailer();
$mailSender->addRecipient($recipient);

$mailSender->setSender('xxxxxxxxxxxxx@libero.it');
$mailSender->addReplyTo('xxxxxxxxxxxxx@libero.it');

$mailSender->setSubject('Richiesta informazioni da sito web');
$mailSender->setBody($myMessage);

if ($mailSender->Send() !== true) {
  $myReplacement = '<span style="color: ' . $error_text_color . ';">' . $errorText . '</span>';
  //header("Location: $url",303);
  print $myReplacement;
  return true;
}
else {
  $myReplacement = '<span style="color: '.$thanksTextColor.';">' . $pageText . '</span>';
  print $myReplacement;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are relaying mail through localhost (you are talking to `127.0.0.1`), so your local sendmail install likely thinks that it is supposed to handle mail for your domain instead of just relaying. There is no user on the system called `info` so it returns an error `550 No such user here`.

Check `/etc/mail/local-host-names` and see if the domain is listed there, if it is comment it out and restart sendmail with `service sendmail restart`.

Also verify that you are allowing relay for localhost in `/etc/mail/access`, my file looks like this on CentOS 5.8 and Sendmail 8.13.8

```
Connect:localhost.localdomain           RELAY
Connect:localhost                       RELAY
Connect:127.0.0.1                       RELAY
```

Another option is to use the real mail server as an SMTP relay instead of sendmail on `localhost` - I can't say what it is for the domain in question, but probably `smtp.example.com` or `mail.example.com`. One additional caveat is that this server may require authentication to relay mail from your web server - you would need to check with your administrator and update your PHP code accordingly.

Comment: I don't have control on the webmail nor on the server of my client's company I only have ftp access to the root of the site I'm currently making. 
Can I do the tests you advised to me with a php script?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you would need root or sudo access to change that file.

Comment: One other option is to *not* send the mail via the localhost SMTP server. You do lose some robustness (if your web server can't get to the mail server) but it should work. Hard to say what the host is, but probably mail.example.com or smtp.example.com. Answer update accordingly

Comment: I had a similiar issue. This fixed the problem for me http://serverfault.com/questions/65365/disable-local-delivery-in-sendmail/128450#128450'

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because the sender's email is not a registered member of the mailing list you're trying to send the email to. some mailing list only accept emails from email addresses registered as member (can be managed in allowed sender, in the mailing list's option).

Answer (score 0):

let me see if i got what you told me:
1) the server that hosts my joomla website has a mail 'engine' that manages requests for mail sending;
2) given that the recipient info@xxxxxx.it is on same mail server that collect the request it calls 127.0.0.1;

3)cannot find a user called info;

the fact is that I don't have any control on my client's company webmail nor webserver.

Can i mask the request in order to not show it comes from localhost? Any other solution?
Sorry for my bad English....